# Can I perform two-sample t-test on z-scores?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, group-differences, standardization, z-score

I want to test for a difference in means between two sets of data. The data is standardized using $(X-\mu)/\sigma$. Can I perform two-sample t-test for a difference in means? In general, since I have standardized through mean shift, which means I've set the means at 0, should I expect mean difference at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not. Once the distribution is standardized, it has a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one. What you should do is go back to the original data and t-test that, that is, if you are sure it is at least approximately normally distributed.

Comment: Many thanks. But my issue is that each observation in my data is the sum of ten standardized values. I've done this to build an index and now I'd like to see whether different groups have different means or not. Any suggestion? @Carl

Comment: If they do not have the same means, then they are not normally distributed. All you will be doing is testing your assumptions.

Comment: @Carl I don't understand how you conclude that they're not normally distributed if they don't have the same means. If they're internallly standardized, don't they all necessarily have the same means no matter what the distribution?

Comment: @Glen_b The mean, median and mode of a skewed distribution are different. If one normalizes non-normal data to have equal mean and standard deviation, and we then discover that there is a significant bias between several different attempts at doing this, then all we are doing is quantifying how bad our assumption of normality was.

Comment: @Glen_b Maybe this will help. There is a difference between the expected value of a Beta distribution with a peak, and its best measure of location.

Comment: @Glen_b OK, maybe I am misinterpreting what is going on. Let us assume that the mean and standard deviation estimates are from 10 values, and that those values are from a perfectly normal distribution. Then the mean and standard deviation of the transformed values should be 0 and 1 respectively. Now suppose that the underlying distribution was really Cauchy, and we took a mean and standard deviation and discover that our mean and standard deviation transformed data has a different mean and standard deviation than 0 and 1. What would that prove?

Comment: Earlier you were talking about skewness, non-normality and bias ... now you seem to be talking about a symmetric distribution without moments at all. I'm afraid I really have no clear sense of what you're trying to say here or how this relates to your earlier comments.

Comment: Glen_b You are correct, I was confused. I just played with numbers a bit. If the mean and sd of any collection of numbers, no matter how bizarre, are re-scaled to be 0 and 1, then the rescaled bizarre numbers have mean zero and SD one.